# Dynamic block with "for each" in a variable with a list - Terraform

Tags: for-loop, terraform, kubernetes-ingress

I have this resource and this dynamic block with this variables:

```
variable "services" {
  description = "Map of the Services"
  type = map(object({
    port                           = number
    uri                            = optional(string)
  }))
}
```

```
services = {

  "auth-service" = {
    port              = 3050
    uri               = "example1"
   }

"clone-service" = {
    port              = 3040
   }

}
```

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "eks_global_ingress" {

[...]

dynamic "rule" {
     # I make this expression to bypass the services that doesn't have URI.
      for_each = { for k, v in var.services : k => v if v["uri"] != null }
      content {
        http {
          path {
            path = "/${rule.value["uri"]}/*"
            backend {
              service {
                name = "${rule.key}-i-svc"
                port {
                  number = rule.value["port"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

At this point everything is ok, but now i want to add another URI to the same service. So i make a list in the URI like below:

```
services = {
  "auth-service" = {
    port              = 3050
    uri               = ["example1","example2]
  "clone-service" = {
    port              = 3040
```

But with this i cant include another for_each in the Dynamic Block. How can i filter null URI and at the same time, loop the code with 2 or more URI as a list?

I expect that the rule is duplicated "x" times over the number of URI present on the list, and if a URI value is not present on the map (null) the "for_each" bypass this rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is completely possible to use more dynamic blocks inside another dynamic block
2. The parameter http.path  is a [list too](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/ingress_v1#path:%7E:text=Path%20array%20of%20path%20regex%20associated) of blocks so you should be able to do something like this:

```hcl
      dynamic "rule" {
     # I make this expression to bypass the services that doesn't have URI.
      for_each = { for k, v in var.services : k => v if length(v["uri"]) > 0 }
      content {
        http {
          dynamic "path" {
            for_each = toset(rule.value["uri"])
            content {
              path = "/${path.key}/*"
              backend {
                service {
                  name = "${rule.key}-i-svc"
                  port {
                    number = rule.value["port"]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Note: don't forget change the uri type from string to list(string)